# how to use multiple conditions in IF statement in ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

In Ampscript, how does would you write multiple conditions in a IF statement. for example I want all conditions to be true in the IF statement

```
set @var1=0
set @var2=0
set @var3=1

if (@var1 == 0 && @var2==0 && @var3 == 0) then
```

is this the correct way to do it in Ampscript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace the `&&` with `AND`.  Also `||` is `OR`.

```
set @var1=0
set @var2=0
set @var3=1

if (@var1 == 0 AND @var2 == 0 AND @var3 == 0) then
```